# The proper way to backup

Tags: ssh, rsync, backup, restic

I want do regular, automated backups to a raspberry pi in my homenetwork. It is sufficient to do backups, when at home.

Every singe guide I read on 'how to do automated backups' tells me to put a passwordless ssh-key on my pi. I don't want to do this, because anyone with access to my pc, would have access to my backups which completely annihilates one purpose of backups.

My current solution is a password protected ssh-key and a rsync script. It took some time to make it work, but now I am prompted for the password as soon as I login at my home network, followed by a backup.

Now I want to use `restic` since I need some type of versioned backup. Also I want to backup other devices as well. The restic guide, again tells me to use a passwordless ssh-key.

Now, I had the idea to do it the other way around. I.e. my (offline) pi can ssh into my laptop without password (but resticted to `resric` use). I could run some systemd.timer with a script that checks if my laptop is reachable and start a backup, if this is the case.

However, this seems quite hacky and I am convinced that this is some common szenario. But I can't find any guides for it.

Can you point me into a general direction? Even some terminology would help, so I can find more information on what I want to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining `restic` with `rclone` allows you to set up a service on a backup server using `rclone` that serves a `restic` REST API that `restic` can connect to from the machine(s) that you want to back up.  Using the REST API is usually *much* faster than using `restic` over SFTP.

This is well documented by `rclone serve restic --help`, including how to use SSL and how to do `htpasswd` authentication.  *You should read that documentation carefully*. If your backup server is public-facing (it shouldn't be), or if you do this for some non-personal setup, you will need to secure it with some way of authenticating individual users.

The minimum you need to set it up to be usable from outside of `localhost` on a local network is the following on the host that serves as the backup server:

```bash
rclone serve restic --addr :8080 /var/backup/restic
```

Here, `/var/backup/restic` is the path under which you want to store your `restic` repositories (the user that runs the above command needs to have write permissions there, so you might want to create a dedicated service user for that).  The `--addr :8080` means "bind to port 8080 on all available interfaces" (by default, `rclone` binds only to `localhost:8080`).

You may then connect to this with the following (this initializes a `restic` repository and creates the first snapshot of my home directory):

```bash
restic -r rest:http://backupsrv:8080/testrepo init
restic -r rest:http://backupsrv:8080/testrepo backup "$HOME"
```

This assumes that you want to create and use a `restic` repository called `testrepo` and that your backup server is accessible as `backupsrv`.  You should replace that hostname with the correct name or IP number.

This will prompt you interactively for the repository password, but you can obviously pass that in the `RESTIC_PASSWORD` environment variable as usual (just like you can pass the `restic` repository in `RESTIC_REPOSITORY` instead of using `-r ...`).

---

On my personal Synology NAS, I run the following Docker container (this is a `docker-compose.yml` file):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  rclone:
    image: rclone/rclone:latest
    container_name: rclone
    hostname: diskstation.local
    ports:
      - 18080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ["serve","restic","/backup"]
    environment:
      - RCLONE_ADDR=0.0.0.0:8080
      - RCLONE_STATS=1h
      - RCLONE_VERBOSE=1

    volumes:
      - /volume1/Restic/backup:/backup
```

This serves the `restic` REST API on port 18080 on the NAS and lets me store my backups in `/volume1/Restic/backup` (by means of a bind mount into the container).  Note that the security in the `rclone` setup is minimal as this is a personal NAS in a walled-off LAN (behind both a firewall and a carrier-grade NAT).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have a passwordless key that's restricted to specific operations.

For example, with Restic (which apparently stores backups via SFTP) or with plain rsync, you could have the backup server maintain Btrfs/ZFS snapshots of the backup disk, with the SSH key accessing an account without root privileges (and therefore with no way to delete snapshots). Should someone use the key to remotely delete the Restic repository, it would take a few seconds to restore it from the last snapshot and then you'd proceed with laptop restore as normal.

With programs like Borg Backup, which have their own "server" that they talk to over SSH, you can restrict the key to a specific forced remote command only, so that all it can do is start the Borg server and not SFTP nor a shell. Borg has an "append-only" option that you can use in the forced command, making the key only usable for uploading new backups but not for deleting old ones.

Arguably, however, if someone 1) has access to your laptop's unencrypted files and 2) is connected to your home network, then you most likely have bigger problems...

Answer (score 1):

> Every singe guide I read on 'how to do automated backups' tells me to put a passwordless ssh-key on my pi. I don't want to do this, because anyone with access to my pc, would have access to my backups which completely annihilates one purpose of backups.

The first statement is correct but let me try to explain what I understand by this. (As well as handling principle of least privilege.)

1. You have a PC that you want to backup
2. You want to protect your backups so that someone/something with unexpected access to your PC cannot break your backups

The solution here is to drive the backups from the backups server (your Pi) rather than from your PC. If you're going to use `rsync` with either `ssh` (to a Linux/Mac client) or with `rsyncd` (a Windows client) you set the scheme up so that the Pi can access the PC. (The PC need have no passwordless access to the Pi.)

A typical approach might be to use `cron` on the Pi to try and backup the PC on a frequent basis (four-hourly, say), but once it has succeeded not to retry until the follow day. This script is untested but should give you the bones for a solution. It's important to note that the `timeout 4h` should be sufficient for a complete backup:

```
basedir=/data/backup_dir                      # Backups target directory
my_pc=192.168.130.33                          # Your PC name or IP address

today=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')                     # Today
stamp=$(cat "$basedir/.stamp" 2>/dev/null)    # Date of last backup

if [ "$today" = "$stamp" ]
then
    # Last backup was today
    exit 0
fi

if ! ping -q -c1 "$my_pc"
then
    # PC not responding to ping
    exit 1
fi

# Backup your PC
if timeout 4h rsync -a "$my_pc":/…/ "$basedir/$today"
then
    # Success
    echo "$today" >"$basedir/.stamp"
    exit 0
fi
```